# Is there some tool to link Elasticsearch with Apache Cassandra?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an Apache Cassandra cluster and I want to use an Elasticsearch cluster to index (some of) the data in Cassandra for fast querying. Is there a library or plugin to do that? I do not want to change my cassandra implementation to adapt to some other non-official Cassandra fork.

Comment: Rivers are removed from elasticsearch 5.x and were deprecated in 2.x... so basically you have to write your own code to read data from cassandra and push to es

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to collect your data from Cassandra. It's part of Elasticsearch stack, so you can easilly integrate with your running Elasticsearch instance.

Comment: Logstash does not support Cassandra as input plugin. Is there some publicly available 3rd party plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

With logstash [I'm referring to 6.1.3] and JDBC driver for cassandra you can pull the data from cassandra with specific schedule.

The driver you can refer from this site [http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html][1]

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042"
    jdbc_user => "*****"
    jdbc_password => "*****"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/path/cassandrajdbc1.1.jar"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM keyspace.table"
  }
}
```

The logstash output can be mapped to elastic search with proper index as you need.

You can refer more about paging and limit parameters for jdbc input in [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html][2]